# Returning the actual value of maximum of absolutes of variables

Tags: c++

I want to find the maximum of the absolute of two variables, and return the actual value of that variable, rather than the absolute value of that variable.

For example:

```
int x = 3;
int y = -5;
int z = max(abs(x), abs(y))
```

Will just set `z` to `5`, whereas I want it to return `-5`. Is there a C++ function to perform this?

Comment: Write your own, it's not that difficult.

Comment: Unlikely, as that's very specific.  Why not simply `z = (abs(x) > abs(y)) ? x : y`?  (Note that neither version will work for `INT_MIN`, though...)

Comment: I doubt there's an already-available standard function for that, but what prevents you from writing your own? it seems pretty trivial to implement using two pairs of iterators and `std::max_element`.

Comment: No there isn't. IMO that's too obscure of a use case to be included in the standard library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int z = (max(abs(x), abs(y)) == abs(x)) ? x : y;
```

This is like an if-condition. Its equivalent to

```
int z = x;
if(max(abs(x), abs(y)) != abs(z))
    z = y;
```

But much shorter.

There is no function in the STL to fit into your needs directly, so you need to make your own and this one could be one version.

A more handy one can be `int z = (abs(y) < abs(x)) ? x : y` thought.

Comment: Why has this been downvoted? Sure, it could do with some more text explaining it, but there's nothing **wrong** with what is there. +1

Comment: @OMGtechy I didn't downvote, but `max(abs(x), abs(y)) == abs(x)` is an unnecessarily verbose and complicated way to write `abs(x) > abs(y)`

Answer (score 7):

If you're using C++11, with the STL you could use a `vector` of int, `max_element` and a lambda `Compare`

```
std::vector<int> values = {3, -5};
int largest_abs = *std::max_element(values.begin(), values.end(), [](const int& a, const int& b)
{
    return abs(a) < abs(b);
});
```

This returns the iterator between the start and end of `values`, whose absolute value is the largest. (this is found through the comparator) The `*` is then used to convert the iterator (returned by `std::max_element`) to an `int`

Answer (score 4):

It's not a commonly used function, but writing your own function is trivial.

```
int max_abs(int x, int y)
{
    if (x == INT_MIN || y == INT_MIN)
        return INT_MIN;
    return (abs(x) > abs(y)) ? x : y;
}
```

Comment: I like this  answer since it takes in account the possibility of an overflow.